# html datalist cause validation error in safari

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, safari

I have an AngularJs 1.x app where I added a html5 datalist element. I know this is not supported in Safari. For now that is not a big issue and I can always create or add a polyfill later on.

However there is some behavior I cannot seem to figure out. The datalist is on a form and it always has an invalid state on that field.

```
<input type="text" name="description" maxlength="40" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="40" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="quote.description" required="" list="standard-remarks" />
<datalist id="standard-remarks">
    <select style="display: none;">
        <option ng-repeat="d in standardQuoteDescription" value="{{d.Description}}">
    </select>
</datalist>
```

My idea would be detecting in the safari in JavaScript and somehow change the validation or removing the datalist element. However that feels pretty odd to do.

Could anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong and/or how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error was caused by a polyfill that I used. After I check it more closely, it was very old and not suitable for this scenario.